# Recurrence of Markov chain on $\mathbb Z \times \{0,1\}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $Z_n = (X_n,Y_n)$ be the Markov chain with values in $E:=\mathbb Z \times \{0,1\}$ starting in $(0,0)$ and symmetric transition probabilities for every $x\in E$, i.e. $1/3$ for going to left, right or changing between $0$ and $1$ in second coordinate.

I have proved that the projections on $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are recurrent, but since the two are not independent this does not suffice to proof $Z_n$ is recurrent on $E$.

How can one prove that $Z_n$ is recurrent on $E$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(X_n)$ is recurrent, $(Z_n)$ will hit the set $\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$ infinitely often with probability 1. Thus, at least one of the states $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ is recurrent, and since the chain is irreducible, all states are recurrent.